# @Repository instance is null when invoking a method using a @Service instance from a unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, jpa

My goal is to use an in-memory database for these unit tests, and those dependancies are listed as:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
```

So that the repository instance actually interacts with a DB, and I dont just mock return values.

The problem is that when I run my unit test, the repository instance inside the service instance is `null`.

Why is that? Am I missing some annotation on the unit test class to initialise the repository instance?

This is the console output when running my unit test:

```
null

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.my.MyService.findAll(MyService.java:20)
    at com.my.MyTest.testMy(MyTest.java:23)
```

My unit test class:

```
public class MyTest {

  @MockBean
  MyRepository myRepository;

  @Test
  void testMy() {
    MyService myService = new MyService();
    int size = myService.findAll().size();
    Assertions.assertEquals(0, size);
  }
}
```

My service class:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    MyRepository myRepository;

    public List<MyEntity> findAll() {

        System.out.println(myRepository); // null
        return (List<MyEntity>) myRepository.findAll(); // throws NullPointerException
    }

    @Transactional
    public MyEntity create(MyEntity myEntity) {

        myRepository.save(myEntity);

        return myEntity;
    }
}
```

My repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

}
```

My entity class:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is that? Am I missing some annotation on the unit test class to initialise the repository instance?

Basically yes :)

You need to initialise a Spring Context by Annotating your Testclass with `@SpringBootTest`

The other Problem you have is that you create your `MyService` Object manually.
By doing so SpringBoot has no chance to inject any Bean for you. You can fix this by simply injecting your `MyService` in your Testclass. Your Code should look something like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    void testMy() {
        int size = myService.findAll().size();
        assertEquals(0, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the @SpringBootTest annotation necessary?, you'r answer is correct,  but I don't see why it wouldn't work without. Is it because you use different beans?

Comment: @YannickMussche OP wants to test the `MyService` in combination with the `MyRepository` and an in-memory database. Other than the title suggests, this is an integration test and not a unit test. Therefore, I suggested using the `@SpringBootTest` annotation. There would be other options, but I think it`s the clearest and easiest.

Answer (score 1):

To use `@MockBean` annotation, you have to use SpringRunner to run the test. Use `@RunWith` Annotation on top of your test class and pass `SpringRunner.class`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

  @MockBean
  MyRepository myRepository;

  @Test
  void testMy() {
    MyService myService = new MyService();
    int size = myService.findAll().size();
    Assertions.assertEquals(0, size);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wish to write an integration test. Here you could remove the MockBean annotation and simply autowire your repository. Also, run with The SpringRunner class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

  @Autowired
  MyRepository myRepository;

  @Autowired
  MyService myService
  
  @Test
  void testMy() {
   int size = myService.findAll().size();
   Assertions.assertEquals(0, size);
  }
}
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your service implementation. Using `@Autowired` to inject the dependency will work when you run the whole app, but it do not allow you to inject a custom dependency when you'll need it, and a good example of this is testing.

Change your service implementation to:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public MyService(MyRepository myRepository){
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    public List<MyEntity> findAll() {

        System.out.println(myRepository); // null
        return (List<MyEntity>) myRepository.findAll(); // throws NullPointerException
    }

    @Transactional
    public MyEntity create(MyEntity myEntity) {

        myRepository.save(myEntity);

        return myEntity;
    }
}
```

This constructor will be called by spring. Then change your test to:

```
public class MyTest {

  @Mock
  MyRepository myRepository;

  @Test
  void testMy() {
    MyService myService = new MyService(myRepository);
    int size = myService.findAll().size();
    Assertions.assertEquals(0, size);
  }
}
```

Note I have replaced `@MockBean` to `@Mock` as the previous annotation is for injecting a mock bean into the spring context, which is not needed if you're doing unit testing. If you want to boot spring context (which I would not recommend you) you need to configure your test class with `@SpringBootTest` or some of the other available alternatives. That will convert your test into an integration test.

PD: This test will not work if you don't provide a mock to `myRepository.findAll()`. Mockito default behaviour is to return null, but you're expecting it to return 0, so you'll need to do something like `given(myRepository.findAll()).willReturn(0)`.

Comment: Thanks for the info here. But I did outline that I'm hoping to do an integration styled test, whereby I don't mock responses for `myRepository.findAll()`. I would like a proper query to the in-memory db to return a result of 0/null .. since I have not inserted any objects into the DB at this point.